# Click( ) function of HtmlUnit not working

Tags: java, htmlunit

I was trying to login to yahoo pipes account (using the login page) with a program. Below is the code I am using. On clicking the "Sign In" button  this page http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/ should open. But looks like the click() function is not working properly. Since the contents of pages before and after the clicking the "Sign In" button are same. This code returns true.

I am not able to figure out whats going wrong. Can someone suggest what I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this:

```
webClient.setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
// You can re-enable JS later
```

Then, remove this:

```
webClient.setRefreshHandler(new RefreshHandler() {
    public void handleRefresh(Page page, URL url, int arg) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("handleRefresh");
    }
});
```